# cfm inside a jsp: how to get a variable from the jsp to the cfm?

Tags: java, jsp, variables, coldfusion, scriptlet

I'm trying to get a variable passed from one jsp page to an imported cfm inside that jsp.

Here is the how the string is stored (http://www.tenaquip.com/shop/optin-form-test.jsp?lang=en):

```
<%  
    String email_address = "test@test.com"; 
%>
```

It needs to be passed to a c:import cfm:

```
<c:import url="https://www.tenaquip.com/cfusion/forms/joinmailing_eng-test.cfm"/>
```

Comment: It seems that to be able to see a variable outside a scriptlet, you need to pass it out:
    <% 
         String email_address = "test@test.com";
         pageContext.setAttribute("email_address", email_address); 
    %>

Answer (score 1):

The solutions is a 2 step process:

1- Pass the variable out of the scriptlet `<% ... %>` to the rest of the original jsp page:

```
<%
  String email_address = "test@test.com";
  pageContext.setAttribute("email_address_to_send", email_address); 
%>
```

2- Forward the variable to the next page:

```
<c:import url="https://www.tenaquip.com/cfusion/forms/joinmailing_eng-test.cfm">
     <c:param name="email_received">${email_address_to_send}</c:param>
</c:import>
```

Then you can use the variable `#email_received#` in your form

Answer (score 0):

I don't use JSP but a quick google gave me [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/ImportPagewithParameterPassing.htm) and [this from Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Java_6.html)

```
<c:import url="header.jsp">
  <c:param name="title" value="Welcome to Page 1"/>
</c:import>
```

Have you tried anything like it?

After that, should dump your scopes in the cfm page and look for how the variable is being passed.

```
<cfdump var="#form#"/>
<cfdump var="#url#"/>
<cfdump var="#cgi#"/>
```

Comment: Almost there, the only thing I can't get to work is to pass the value of the email as a variable: <c:param name="email_address" value="${email_address.value}"/> returns an empty string.

Comment: @VincentNoiseux try `<c:param name="email_address">"%{email_address}"</c:param>` (from more googling)

Comment: This returns "%{email_address}", not the value stored inside email_address (you can see it if you visit http://www.tenaquip.com/shop/optin-form-test.jsp?lang=en. 
I hate troubleshooting a language I don't know much about ;-)

Comment: Seems I need to pass the variable out of the Scriptlet (I did not know it was a scriptlet until 5 minutes ago):
        <%  
    String email_address = "test@test.com";
    pageContext.setAttribute("email_address", email_address);
   %>
and them the passing of the param works:
     <c:param name="email_address">${email_address}</c:param>
than in the other file can access the variable #email_Address#

Comment: @VincentNoiseux - Not everyone reads comments. You should post the solution as an answer, rather than a comment, so it is easier for the next guy to find.

Comment: @VincentNoiseux Glad you got it working. It's a good practice to scope variables especially when dealing with url or variable, like `#url.email_address#` if it comes from URL. Also, when you do need to include code in a comment, you can surround with backticks (apostrophe-ish key next to 1 key like \`this\` creates `this`). `<cfset example="See how nicely this stands out?">`

Comment: @cfqueryparam Sorry, I tried to add code to the comments, but it does not work the same as the posts. `Thanks for letting me know.`